# database.com JPQL query exception when searching for NULL date fields

Tags: java, database, salesforce, database-com, database-com-sdk

I'm trying to convert an old database system to Salesforce and have decided to try out the Database.com Java SDK.

I have recently hit problem that I can't seem to find a work around related to a JPQL Query when searching for NULL or empty dates.

E.g.

```
select t from table where t.expiryDate is NULL or t.expiryDate = :today
```

This causes the following exception:

```
Caused by: [InvalidFieldFault [ApiQueryFault [ApiFault  exceptionCode='INVALID_FIELD' exceptionMessage='
from Table__c p  where (( p.Expiry_Date__c = 'NULL' ) OR (
                              ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:158
value of filter criterion for field 'Expiry_Date__c' must be of type date and should not be enclosed in quotes'
]
 row='1'
 column='158'
]
]
```

I'm assuming this is a bug in a beta release of the SDK as I don't believe it should be converting the NULL to a string, but please let me know otherwise and/or does anyone know a work around?

Comment: just a guess, did you try with `t.expiryDate = NULL`?

Comment: Worth a try, but no, that didn't work either. I've also tried replacing null with '' and also passing it as a named parameter (of which told me it was expecting NULL).

Comment: It seems like a serious bug to me (so much for their tests, one would imagine date is null should be in tests). Open a ticket?

Comment: Its conversion to soql appears to have a bug, the correct SOQL should be where p.expiry_date__c = null (which'll work fine), i've passed this onto the Java SDK team.

Comment: I created an issue for this: https://github.com/forcedotcom/java-sdk/issues/16. We will take a look at it asap.

Comment: Issues has been resolved